# JAX-WS web service - what if it fails after my method leaves?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

We've got a few JAX-WS web services.  Someone asked me the question of what happens if, AFTER my method returns, in that split nanosecond, the network connection dies, and the client therefore never hears back from us that we succeeded.  Is there a callback wherein we can get control to take action of some kind if the SOAP reponse never actually makes it back to the client?

Comment: what kind of action would you like to take?

Comment: @wero - Well, at this point it's not been decided, but I would suspect they are interested in adding it to our event log as a problem.  This log, separate from the app logs, would let us know that when the client reported failure, that the service would say "no, it worked" and might help us understand how to rectify the situation.

Comment: I just tried creating a jax-ws client app that severed connection abruptly after reading a couple bytes from the response stream in hopes of raising  `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` error while writing the SOAP response in my sample service on Tomcat. I tried creating a Servlet filter for the JAX-WS servlet both the JAX-WS reference impl and Apache Axis2. Neither implementation raises an exception to the filter chain - both seem to trap Throwable such that the servlet filter has no chance to catch a raised IOException.  Your only recourse may be at the socket level somehow.

Comment: I should add, with JAX-WS RI, the `WSServlet` at least logged `SEVERE: caught throwable
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` but never re-raised. Looks like it [definitely traps and swallows throwable](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxws/blob/master/jaxws-ri/servlet/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletDelegate.java#L140).

Comment: Found a picture to describe the attempted approach. In my comment above, the `WSServlet` is the JAX-WS RI endpoint servlet in this [diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/img/wsadv_dt_001.gif)